# Почему разъезжается текст в списке справа?

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно, чтобы текст был выровнен как в примере ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.devices {
    background: url("../img/devices-back.jpg");

    padding: 44px 0 3px;
}

.devices__title {
    color: #f5c506;
    font-size: 43.5px;
    font-family: 'PT Sans';
    /*letter-spacing: 1.5px;*/
    text-transform: uppercase;

    text-align: center;
}

.devices__table {
    display: table;
}

.devices__image {
    display: table-cell;
    min-width: 630px;
}

.devices__list {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}




.content {
    width: 1020px;
    margin: auto;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


.list {
list-style-type: disc;
list-style-position: inside;
color: #f5c506;
font-size: 55px;

padding-left: 8px;
padding-top: 78px;
}

.list__item {
color: #a9a9a7;
font-size: 22px;
font-family: 'Open Sans';

margin-left: -70px;
}
```

```html
<section class="devices">
        <div class="content">
            <h3 class="devices__title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
            <div class="devices__content">
                <div class="devices__image">
                    <img src="img/devices.png" alt="devices">
                </div>
                <div class="devices__list">
                    <ul class="list">
                        <li><span class="list__item">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis</span></li>
                        <li><span class="list__item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing</span></li>
                        <li><span class="list__item">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis</span></li>
                        <li><span class="list__item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Может ещё какие-то стили есть? Посмотри включенные стили в браузере inspect element

Comment: Точно, забыл самое главное. 2 класса снизу: list и list__item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В .list и .list__item не совпадаел размер шрифта  font-size

Убран отступ в .list__item margin-left: -70px;

```css
.devices {
    background: url("../img/devices-back.jpg");

    padding: 44px 0 3px;
}

.devices__title {
    color: #f5c506;
    font-size: 43.5px;
    font-family: 'PT Sans';
    /*letter-spacing: 1.5px;*/
    text-transform: uppercase;

    text-align: center;
}

.devices__table {
    display: table;
}

.devices__image {
    display: table-cell;
    min-width: 630px;
}

.devices__list {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}




.content {
    width: 1020px;
    margin: auto;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


.list {
list-style-type: disc;
list-style-position: inside;
color: #f5c506;
font-size: 22px;

padding-left: 8px;
padding-top: 78px;
text-indent: -20px;
}

.list__item {

color: #a9a9a7;
font-size: 22px;
font-family: 'Open Sans';

margin-left: 0px;

}
```

```html
<section class="devices">
        <div class="content">
            <h3 class="devices__title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
            <div class="devices__content">
                <div class="devices__image">
                    <img src="img/devices.png" alt="devices">
                </div>
                <div class="devices__list">
                    <ul class="list">
                        <li><span class="list__item">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis</span></li>
                        <li><span class="list__item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing</span></li>
                        <li><span class="list__item">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis</span></li>
                        <li><span class="list__item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Спасибо, стало лучше, но это не совсем то. Мне нужно было сразу прикрепить нужный результат. Там отступ от маркера до текста должен быть меньше и сам текст не должен съезжать влево на новой строке.

Comment: Добавил скриншот в текст вопроса.

Comment: Так?...........

Comment: Спасибо) Не готовый вариант, но помогло понять что и как исправить.